# Teams Bot independent of Azure Bot Service

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to develop a Microsoft Teams Bot for interactive communication without going through the step of registering it with Azure Bot Service. If it is possible, are there any Python examples of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible at all. There's tight integration between the two for bots. Importantly, there are two options when creating a bot in Azure:

1. Bot with Web App - this includes a bot registration AS WELL AS hosting using an Azure Web App
2. Bot Channels Registration - this is JUST the registration, which allows a very decent free option, and then also allows you to host your bot in a different Azure hosting option or *anywhere else you like* even (e.g. AWS). So, this is all you really *need* to use and the free allowance might well be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is not necessary to use an Azure Account. I was able to test bots by registering them at https://dev.botframework.com/

Comment: Are you able to access the Azure Portal? If so, I think you'll still find a `bot channels` registration there somewhere, as well as an Azure AD (Entra ID) Application.

Comment: I don't have an Azure Account but I have a MS 365 Developer Account,

Comment: Is it mandatory to register the Bot on Azure Portal for using it in Production? I don't intend to deploy the bot code in Azure but am planning to use AWS.

Comment: if the dev.botframework.com is working for you that's probably fine - it's creating an entry in the Bot Framework Services backend which is really what you need. A Bot "Channels" registration in Azure will do the same thing. You can -host- the bot anywhere, it's just a web backend, so AWS is fine. Where you might run into trouble is that, like the Bot Framework Registration, there should be an Azure AD Application, and that will have a key ("app password") that will probably expire at some point

Comment: if you don't have access via the regular Azure portal, I'm not sure where you'd manage the key expiry.

Comment: I do have Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure AD) access and ability to create client apps. I don't have an Azure Account

Comment: ok great. Maybe log into the portal and see what resources you have access to